# Erro 407 ao conectar in proxy

Tags: c#, visual-studio, proxy

Estou tentando me comunicar com um web service e minha máquina utiliza internet via proxy.
Ao iniciar a comunicação com o web service, da erro de autenticação do proxy.
Como consigo pegar o usuário e senha que utilizo para navegador no browser?
Estou usando visual studio 2010 e C#.

Comment: Poste o código, para poder ajudar.

Comment: Consegui resolver, com o seguinte código:

WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy();
 Uri myUri = new Uri("urlproxy:port");
  proxy.Address = myUri;
  NetworkCredential crediciais = new NetworkCredential("user", "password");
  proxy.Credentials = crediciais;
 objectWebService.Proxy = proxy;

Comment: Você pode responder a sua própria pergunta.

Comment: Existe a possibilidade de utilzar o usuário padrão e senha, adicionando o seguinte código no arquivo app.config
<configuration>
     <system.net>
        <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true">        
        </defaultProxy>
     </system.net>
</configuration>